# Restructuring result of an async method in ES6

Tags: javascript, async-await, destructuring

I've run into an odd problem trying to destructure the return from an async call in ES6. In essence, this is the problem:

```
// Resolves to { foo: { bar: baz } }
const { foo } = await fetchData();

console.log(foo); // { bar: baz }
const { bar } = foo;
console.log(bar); // Undefined
```

I've tried `await foo` as well, and that doesn't seem to work either. From what I understand, the destructuring expression should not execute until fetchData has resolved, and the log statements occur in the expected order, which means that `foo` has a value at the point where the restructuring statement executes. I'm pretty baffled.

Comment: inside the `foo` object, there is another "foo". Might it be the problem?

Comment: Seems fetchData() is returning `{foo: { foo: { bar: baz}}}`

Comment: looks like you want `const { bar } = foo.foo;`

Comment: Oh yes, good point that's an error. Fixed now.

Comment: I am using axios, but I'm restructuring `data` first when I return. I'm actually watching all of this via the debugger, so I'm pretty sure it's not a problem with the structure of the object.

Comment: Indeed, it should be the problem with structure of data only. plz cross check whatever stored in `foo` is an object or string. I feel like it's stringified object thus you could see it in log but can't destructure it.

Comment: I wasn't able to recreate this-- it'd be helpful to know what browser you're using and whether you're using babel and any bundlers. It might be an issue with using constants in an async function. Does `var bar; ({ bar } = foo);` instead of `const { bar } = foo;` have a different result?